# Timer with TimeSpan and self-made timer are slower than Stopwatch

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to develop simple timer which can save its last value and continue from it at the new app start.

`Stopwatch` class is not serializable and even cannot be initialized in order to be started from specific time. But it works great. Benchmark showed that stopwatch's 1 minute is really 1 minute.

I tried to use `TimeSpan` in the following way:

```
private TimeSpan timerNew = new TimeSpan();
private DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timerNew += new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
    TbTimer.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",
        timerNew.Hours, timerNew.Minutes, timerNew.Seconds);
}

private void ButtonStart_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
}

private void ButtonStop_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        dispatcherTimer.Stop();
}

private void ButtonReset_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    timerNew = new TimeSpan();
    TbTimer.Text = "00:00:00";
}
```

When I checked it against real stopwatch, I found out that this timer implementation lost 2 seconds per minute.

I also tried my own Timer implementation which is simple class with `ulong` field, which is incremented on each dispatcherTimer tick. And UI shows results after transformation of seconds to hours, minutes and so on. But it also loses 2 seconds per minute comparing to real stopwatch.

Why these 2 seconds are lost? What is an alternative to `Stopwatch` for usage in a customizable timer?

Comment: That is entirely normal, timers can't get their event handlers running instantly.  Only use the wall clock to measure elapsed time.  DateTime.UtcNow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows thread scheduler is not a "real-time" scheduler, as Windows is not a "real-time OS". In other words, all timing and scheduling is done on a "best effort" basis, without any guarantee of exact precision. In addition, this always results in lost time, because the one guarantee you do have is that scheduling will not happen *early*. So when there's an imprecision, it's always in the direction of "late".

The `Stopwatch` class works because it uses CPU-supported performance counters, which doesn't rely on the OS scheduler. The hardware itself tracks the elapsed time and provides the information you need.

I recommend *against* the use of `DateTime.UtcNow` for measuring elapsed time, for two reasons: first, the clock `DateTime` uses is adjustable, and so even using UTC time (which at least would compensate for automatic adjustments due to Daylight Saving Time) is not guaranteed to be accurate. Second, your specific scenario seems to involve an issue where you want to serialize the current state and restore it, which `DateTime.UtcNow` doesn't address anyway.

Instead, you should make your own serializable stopwatch class, which uses `Stopwatch` itself as the basis, but which stores a base elapsed value that you add to the `Stopwatch`'s elapsed value.

For example:

```
class SerializableStopwatch
{
    public TimeSpan BaseElapsed { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Elapsed { get { return _stopwatch.Elapsed + BaseElapsed; } }

    private Stopwatch _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    // add whatever other members you want/need from the Stopwatch class,
    // simply delegating the operation to the _stopwatch member. For example:

    public void Start() { _stopwatch.Start(); }
    public void Stop() { _stopwatch.Stop(); }
    // etc.
}
```

How exactly you would serialize the above is up to you. In the simplest scenario, you can just format the `Elapsed` property as a string to save the value, and then when you want to restore the object, parse that value, create a new instance of the above class, and then assign the value to the `BaseElapsed` property.

For additional discussion on the topic, you might find Eric Lippert's blog article [Precision and accuracy of DateTime](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime.aspx) useful and interesting.

Comment: Thanks, it is very interesting. And the idea on how to serialize Stopwatch is really cool solution.

Comment: You've got that pretty backwards.  DateTime.UtcNow *is* accurate, kept that way by a time service.  It is Stopwatch that is not accurate, it doesn't get calibrated at all.  Accuracy is only as good as electronic part tolerances, nothing to put any faith in with today's dirt-cheap hardware.

Comment: @HansPassant: did you read Eric's article? Or others on the specific topic? If you want to know what time of day it is, by all means, use `DateTime.UtcNow`. But for measuring _elapsed_ time, it is not reliable. And `Stopwatch` _is_. Please note that the clock used to track time-of-day on a PC (which as you say is often not accurate, hence the need to periodically update via NTP...indeed, this need to update periodically is yet another reason _not_ to use the system clock for measuring elapsed time) is not the same clock used for `Stopwatch`.

Comment: You can reason this out for yourself without a degree in electronics.  If the frequency source for Stopwatch is so fantastically accurate, why did they not also use it to keep the wall clock accurate?

Comment: @HansPassant: the short answer to your question is that to do so would be impractical. There are lots of articles on the web that can explain the difference between the so-called real-time clock used for the PC time-of-day clock and the high-precision clock used by the CPU-based performance counters that `Stopwatch` uses, and which drives the various other high-precision timing needs of the OS (e.g. A/V playback), and why the two are used differently in the OS. And no, you don't need an EE degree, but you should also be wary of following your intuition, as it's not as simple as you think.

Comment: @HansPassant: to get you started, here are some articles you might find interesting: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx, http://performancebydesign.blogspot.com/2012/03/high-resolution-clocks-and-timers-for.html. Bottom-line: PCs equipped with a high-resolution clock (i.e. any modern hardware) have better accuracy with that clock than with the real-time-clock used to support `DateTime.UtcNow`.